# Laravel Auth:Attempt fails on newly created users

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working with Laravel for the past year and a few months ago we created a separate site that uses `Auth::attempt` to log in users. All has been working fine, but recently we noticed that newly created users can't log in.

I'm quite new to Laravel and to authenticating users through Laravel. Can anybody guide me in any direction why this might happen?

Below is our login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'initials'   => 'required|max:5',
    'password' => 'required'
  ]);

  if (Auth::attempt(['initials' => $request->initials, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect()->route('scanner.index');
  }

  return redirect('/')->withInput($request->only('initials', 'remember'));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this `$request->session()->regenerate();` needed?

Comment: We followed the documentation from Laravel, where they specify that you need to use it to prevent session fixation. 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Are you sure you have done the necessary changes required for `initials` instead of `email` in `attempt()` method to be done in any of the config files?

Comment: Yeah, i would be fairly sure - we have been using initials for the past 4 months or so. It is just newly created users and thanks for taken the time to answer!

Comment: No issues. I just said it because you mentioned _we created a separate site_, so maybe something left over, like config replication or any service providers left to be registered etc. From the snippet you showed, it is hard to debug what could have gone wrong.  My only remaining guess is some before or after middleware tweaking any values?

Comment: I should mention that we haven't changed anything since implementing it. I don't know if there could be some sort of cap on users. I know - my bad. We use Sanctum as our authentication system, but i'm just confused why new users cannot log in. 

Is there a way to get an error response from the auth facade? I've tried looking through the docs, but I am kinda lost in terms of debugging techniques.

Comment: I am afraid I am out of clues as well. I am also a little lost with using sessions for SPAs if you are using Laravel sanctum. See if [`this thread`](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unauthenticated-when-using-sanctum-token) is of any help.

Comment: No problem! I will look at the thread and see what I can dig up with. Thanks your helping anyway!

Comment: I would check the app.key if it's another install/copy of the same project, if it's not the same app.key it can prevent some users to login

Comment: Can you support error message?

Comment: @Lk77 I will try your suggestion! Thank you!
@UioSun there aren't any error messages, because `Auth::attempt` only returns true or false as per my understanding. As well as I don't know how to handle errors with the `Auth` facade :/